# How to perform a Dial Call using Ubuntu API

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, phone, qml, sdk

I'd like to know how to perform a Dial Call using Ubuntu API.
I couldn't find anything in the API doc: https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04.1/

thx,